# The Five Cardinals

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> I've got five cardinals, one without its mate.
>
> My house is made of exactly four-hundred and thirty-five nice solid bricks.
>
> (I'm kidding - they're rather fluffy.)
>
> My length is about two hundred and forty-three, give or take.
>
> My bench has nine legs - really, no tricks!
>
> Mathematically, I have some interesting attributes, too:
>
> a hyperbolic trig function in my middle, a quadratic on my left,
>
> and - once a year - a sphere on my right. Yoo-hoo!
>
> My whole is, in a way, a complicated plane shape who from 2D has left.

Note: just for fun, I made a question with the knowledge and trivia tags - see [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6552/should-the-knowledge-tag-be-merged-with-the-trivia-tag?cb=1) for why.

Note: I replaced "chair" with "bench". I think it's a little more accurate this way.

Hint 1:

> The specific trig function is the hyperbolic cosine function. It has a very famous application. That application is what that line's clue is driving at.

Hint 2:

> The sphere exists every 365 days (366 every four years, of course), and is used to celebrate a certain event that happens with that regularity. It is destroyed at the end (or beginning?) of the event.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Edit - Update**

I think the answer is

> The United States of America

I've got five cardinals, one without its mate.

> Five of the U.S. states have cardinal directions in their name: North Carolina, South Carolina, North Dakota, South Dakota and West Virginia - which is the one without the mate as there is no East Virginia. 
>  **Original**: Five major [self-governing territories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territories_of_the_United_States) - two are located in Micronesia and two in the Caribbean. American Samoa, in Polynesia, does not have a mate.

My house is made of exactly four-hundred and thirty-five nice solid bricks.

> The U.S. House of Representatives has 435 voting representatives.

(I'm kidding - they're rather fluffy.)

My length is about two hundred and forty-three, give or take.

> This year it is 243 years since 1776, when the United States declared independence

My bench has nine legs - really, no tricks!

> The Supreme Court of the U.S. has nine justices on its bench.

Mathematically, I have some interesting attributes, too:

a hyperbolic trig function in my middle,

> cosh (as confirmed by OP). I think this refers to the catenary curve, a famous example of which is the [Gateway Arch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway_Arch) in St. Louis, Missouri.

a quadratic on my left,

> A famous example of a parabolic arch is the [Golden Gate Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Gate_Bridge) in California.

and - once year - a sphere on my right. Yoo-hoo!

> This is the [Times Square Ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_Square_Ball) in New York, which drops to celebrate the New Year

My whole is, in a way, a complicated plane shape who from 2D has left.

> Geographically, coastlines are often referred to as fractal in nature so may be attributed with a [fractal dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension). 
> Alternatively, because the U.S. is quite a large country, the amount it curves over the surface of the Earth is quite large compared to most other countries so we can say it is definitely not flat (2D).

**Original answer**

> The U.S. House of Representatives

Comment: You're on the right track. Think a little more broadly. The first clue, btw, relates to a specific (and somewhat rare) use of "cardinal". @hexomino I've added two more hints.

Comment: @Brandon_J okay, I've updated my answer based on your suggestions.

Comment: you are soooooo close. The broad answer is correct, but the cardinal clue isn't quite right, and since it _is_ part of the title, I feel like that should be correct, too, before I give the checkmark. Do a google search for "Cardinal directions."

Comment: @Brandon_J Ah, okay, this is what I thought originally but couldn't get it to quite fit. I've updated now, in line with what I think it might be, is this right?

Comment: lol that's so good but not what I was thinking. Think West Virginia...and _East_ Virginia? @hexomino

Comment: @Brandon_J Ah, yes, of course, that was such a good clue and I danced around it for ages. Sorry, I should have gotten it the first time.

Comment: Now you've got it! @hexomino